# Loop through an object/associative array and retrieve an specific item

Tags: php

I'm receiving a JSON and then decoding it either to object or associative array, then I need to loop through an specific item (results->playerStatus->name).

Here's the structure:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "DEMO",
      "description": "Description",
      "platform": "PLAYER",
      "lastContactInMinutes": null,
      "group": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Group DEMO"
      },
      "playerStatus": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Never accessed",
        "time": 0
      },
      "playlists": {
        "0": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Playlist DEMO"
        },
        "1": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Playlist DEMO"
        },
        "2": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Playlist DEMO"
        },
        "3": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Playlist DEMO"
        },
        "4": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Playlist DEMO"
        },
        "5": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Playlist DEMO"
        },
        "6": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Playlist DEMO"
        }
      },
      "audios": {
        "0": null
      }
    }]
}
```

Here's what I tried

```
$object = json_decode($feed);

foreach ($object->results->playerStatus->name as $p) {

echo $p;

}
```

I got an error 'cause, obviously, I don't know the correct syntax.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''results'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)
```

What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Comment: How do you get the value of `$feed`?

Comment: You can't loop `results->playerStatus->name` because its a string _Never accessed_, did  you mean get all `name` from each array in `playlists`?

Comment: Also, that's a parse error, however there is no parse error in your code.

Comment: @NigelRen

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "myURL",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Secret-Token: mytoken"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$feed = json_decode($response);

Comment: @AbraCadaver there are several playerStatus items to loop through, but yes I need to retrive the "name" value of each of of them.

Comment: So you decode `$response` into `$feed` and then you decode `$feed` again into `$object`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver no that was a mistake I made while editing and pasting the question...

Answer (score 0):

The array is `$object->results`, you need to do the looping at that level, then access the contents using object notation.

```
foreach ($object->results as $result) {
    $name = $result->playerStatus->name;
    echo $name;
}
```